# Running a custom query inside another cpt single and trying to grab a variable

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, taxonomy, tax-query

I made a cpt "Neighborhoods" for different neighborhoods.

On the Neighborhoods archive, you click on one and go to the single.

All good.

an example url is /blog/neighborhoods/south-austin/

But I'm trying to run a wp_query on that single looking for all properties in that are in that neighborhood.

I created a custom taxonomy called "prop_neighborhood" that I assigned to the "client_prop" cpt. I can call it manually like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'client_prop',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'tax_query' => array(
   array(
    'taxonomy' => 'prop_neighborhood',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'south-austin',
    )
  )
);
```

But then I have make a template for each one. How can I make the "terms" pull in the current  post title slug, save it as a variable and insert it where "south-austin" is?

I'm thinking this would be a good way to run it, as long as the page title url matches the taxonomy slug it will call it in correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
global $post;   // make sure the post object is available
$slug = $post->post_name;  // get the slug

// insert the slug into your query
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'client_prop',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'tax_query' => array(
   array(
    'taxonomy' => 'prop_neighborhood',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $slug,
    )
  )
);
```